# C program football team structure with pointer elements and dynamic allocation

Tags: c

I have a question about passing function to another function which both have structure as arguments. First I created two structures:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[25],surname[25];int number;
}PLAYER;

typedef struct
{
    char nameofteam[25];int numberofplayers;char *players;
}TEAM;
```

Then I defined a function to read elements of one player:

```
void readplayer(PLAYER *);
void readplayer(PLAYER *pi)
{
    printf("name:");scanf("%s",pi->name);
    printf("surname:");scanf("%s",pi->surname);
    printf("number of player:");scanf("%d",&pi->number);
}
```

My question is how to create function which prototype is `void readteam(TEAM*)` which will read data for one team, but using function `readplayer` and call it in `main()`? Here is what I have tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    char name[25],surname[25];int number;
}PLAYER;

typedef struct
{
    char nameofteam[25];int numberofplayers;char *players;
}TEAM;
void readplayer(PLAYER *pi)
{
    printf("name:");scanf("%s",pi->name);
    printf("surname:");scanf("%s",pi->surname);
    printf("number of player:");scanf("%d",&pi->number);
}
void readteam(TEAM *pt)
{
 char players[101];int i;
 printf("name of team:");scanf("%s",pt->nameofteam);
 printf("number of players in team:");scanf("%d",&pt->numberofplayers);
 printf("players:");scanf("%s",players);
 pt->players=(char *)calloc(length(players)+1,sizeof(char));
 copy(pt->players,players);
 for(i=0;i<pt->numberofplayers;i++)
 {
     printf("%d.",i+1);
     readplayer(pt+i);
 }
}
void erase(TEAM *);
void erase(TEAM *pt)
{
    free(pt->players);
}
int length(char *s)
{
    int d=-1;
    while(s[++d]);
    return d;
}

void copy(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    while(*s1++ = *s2++);
}
int main()
{
 int i,n;
 TEAM *p;
 do
 {
     printf("n=");scanf("%d",&n);
 }
 while(n<1);
 p=(TEAM *)malloc(n * sizeof(TEAM));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     printf("%d.",i+1);readteam(p+i);
 }
 free(p);
}
```

This gives me an error at the last input (in compiling, not debugging). Must be because of inappropriate use of dynamic allocation. I didn't use `<string.h` library. Obviously, only the `readteam` function has to be in `main()`.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Gives you "an error"?  Would you like to tell us what this error is?

Comment: You certainly want `PLAYER *players` instead if `char *players` in your `TEAM` struct, no?

Comment: The code `pt->players=(char *)calloc(length(players)+1,sizeof(char));` seems strange. players is a string. But as others have said: describe the error...

Comment: error: .exe has stop working

Comment: This is often caused by dinamic allocation when it is not well used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused on how to store the playsrs. You have created a `PLAYER` struct, but you never use it. Instead, you insist that players must be a single string.

But it should work like this: You have `n` teams. Ecah team has `m` players. All team info is stored in your ´TEAM`struct. All player info is stored in your`PLAYER`struct. Because a team is made up of players, there should be a`PLAYER` entry in your struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    char surname[25];
    int number;
} PLAYER;

typedef struct {
    char nameofteam[25];
    int numberofplayers;
    PLAYER *players;
} TEAM;
```

Then, when you read players, you read the bare team info in `readteam`. But you don't read anything about individual players there, because you delegate that to `readplayer`. Of course, the pointer you pass to that function must be that for a player, not one for a team:

```
void readplayer(PLAYER * pi)
{
    printf("name:");
    scanf("%s", pi->name);
    printf("surname:");
    scanf("%s", pi->surname);
    printf("number of player:");
    scanf("%d", &pi->number);
}

void readteam(TEAM * pt)
{
    int i;

    printf("name of team:");
    scanf("%s", pt->nameofteam);
    printf("number of players in team:");
    scanf("%d", &pt->numberofplayers);

    pt->players = calloc(pt->numberofplayers, sizeof(*pt->players));

    for (i = 0; i < pt->numberofplayers; i++) {
        printf("Player %d:\n", i + 1);
        readplayer(pt->players + i);
    }
}
```

Your cast to `(char *)` hides the warning about incompatible types. You should cast only when you know what you're doing. In this simple program, you don't need casts.

In your original code, there are warnings about "implicit declarations". These concern your `copy` and `length` functions. (By the way, what's wrong with `strlen` and `strcpy`?) You should move these functions to the top so that they are declared before they are called. ALternatively, provide prototypes at the beginning of your code or in a header file, which you `#include` at the top. (But now that you read into `PLAYER` structs, these functions are no longer needed.)

Comment: How to call the function in main()?

Comment: Just the way you do. (It's not a good design, because the client code shouldn't worry about allocation details, but it should work.)

Comment: I have figured it out.